# unable to list/access files inside schroot from a `mount --bind`

Tags: mount, bind-mount, schroot

I created the chroot with `schroot` following these instructions: https://wiki.winehq.org/Building_Wine#Chroot

Then to test it I did:

```
$ sudo mkdir /TestA
$ echo abc |sudo tee /TestA/tst.txt

$ cat /TestA/tst.txt
abc

$ ls -ld /TestA /TestA/tst.txt
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep 17 03:02 /TestA
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    4 Sep 17 03:02 /TestA/tst.txt

$ sudo mkdir /srv/chroot/ubuntu_i386/TestB/
$ sudo mount -o bind /TestA/ /srv/chroot/ubuntu_i386/TestB/
$ mount |grep Test
/dev/mapper/MyLvmGroup-something on /srv/chroot/ubuntu_i386/TestB type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)

$ schroot -c ubuntu_i386 -u root
$ ls -ld /TestB /TestB/tst.txt
ls: cannot access '/TestB/tst.txt': No such file or directory
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep 17 06:10 /TestB
$ ls -l /TestB
total 0
```

I tried it also in a non LVM partition as the bind source, and it did not work.

What is happening? everywhere ppl saying it works, why it is not working here? what am I missing?

ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

`schroot` actually uses `/run/schroot/mount/ubuntu_i386-...`
and for **each new chroot** on it, it uses a new huge ID after `ubuntu_i386-`

just check the auto mount/binds already there with:
`mount |grep ubuntu_i386`

So the solution is:
Find out the new mount directory after running `schroot`,
then mount properly ex.:
`sudo mount -o bind /TestA /run/schroot/mount/ubuntu_i386-aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee/TestB`